# AutoHotkey remap keys to swich two keys with each other

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AHK and I wanted to make a script that remaps all the number keys to the relative symbol above it and the symbol to the number. So for example when I press 2 "@" is printed, and SHIFT+2 actually prints 2.

my code is as follows:

```
2::send @
@::send 2
```

and so on for all other number keys...

but apparently the @ printed by the first `send` triggers the second and it gets stuck in a loop.
I know it's probably a stupid and basic mistake but I couldn't find anything about how to go around this. Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Is this question purely academic? A simple and obvious solution would be to toggle NUMLOCK, no script needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the shift key (which is how you get to @ anyway) and the `$` keyboard hook modifier (so the hotkey is only activated if actually pressed):

```
$2::send @
$+2::send 2
```

and so on for all other number keys...

Comment: @Skipjack3 well then accepting it might not be the best idea, because you probably won't get any more answers.. btw, see Key Remapping, might be what you're looking for

Comment: Good point, I had accepted it before trying it out, I was too confident.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work . . . For me the `2::send @` and `+2::send 2` gives an error: `71 hotkeys have been received in the last 1125ms. Do you want to continue?` but `$2::send @` and `$+2::send 2` works perfectly to swap those two keys.  Maybe it's your send mode?  Try it with `sendinput` or even like this: `$2::@` and `$+2::SendInput 2` and tell us if you get an error or if nothing happens (nothing typed) or if no re-mapping occurs.

Comment: Btw, I edited my answer to remove the `#InstallKeybdHook` reference because that did not work for me.  You should use just the `$` prefix modifier.

Comment: I got the same error as @PGilm because I tried using `#InstallKeybdHook` but with the idividual $ it works.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to an existing .ahk file and confirmed it does exactly what you want.

```
$1::SendRaw !
$!::SendRaw 1
$2::SendRaw @
$@::SendRaw 2
$3::SendRaw #
$#::SendRaw 3
$4::SendRaw $
$$::SendRaw 4
$5::SendRaw `%
$%::SendRaw 5
$6::SendRaw ^
$^::SendRaw 6
$7::SendRaw &
$&::SendRaw 7
$8::SendRaw *
$*::SendRaw 8
$9::SendRaw (
$(::SendRaw 9
$0::SendRaw )
$)::SendRaw 0
```